# how to create a remote project in netbeans pointing to a git clone folder

Tags: git, netbeans

Is it possible to create PHP project in netbeans from a git clone in remote server, and manage its git action (add, commit, etc) from inside netbeans?

Say I have a git clone is Server1:/var/www-git-clone. 
In netbeans, it's possible to create a project for remote folder pointing to it, but for some reason, it is not recognized as a git project.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the project was originally created with Netbeans Team-> Git->Clone.. should clone it and then find any Netbeans projects inside.

I don't program in PHP, and the projects for different languages can be different but I believe that in order for the folder to be recognized as a project it needs to have an nbproject subdirectory with a number of Netbeans created files. If yours doesn't have that, create a new project  with the appropriate "with Existing Sources" project type and then select your cloned sources  as the sources for the new project.

**Update**

Regarding:

> is there any way to let netbeans to manipulate the git command for a git clone?

The question still doesn't make much sense. A git clone copies a directory, its subdirectories and version history from a remote server to your local machine. Once on your local machine you make whatever changes you want and if you have permission can push those changes back to the original server (Team -> Commit followed by Team -> Remote -> Push changes to Upstream) . It could be that the top-level directory of the clone is also a Netbeans project directory or there could be multiple netbeans projects distributed in sub-directories or the clone could have no Netbeans projects. You can create a New netbeans project within that directory or in a completely seperate directory on your computer with a reference to the sources in that directory. Git is not a method to deploy your application to a remote web server, it is a way of sharing your source with other developers or making backups.

Comment: The git clone folder exists on the remote server, and I tried to create new project "from remote server". What I'm asking is, is there any way to let netbeans to manipulate the git command for a git clone that is in remote server?

Comment: Hi [ndriks](http://stackoverflow.com/users/712775/ndriks), then the answer is no. Plain NetBeans can neither execute nor manipulate a remote git command. But it sure can handle local git repositories and push to the server. The best setup (in my experience) is what [Will](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5171540/willshackleford) has already suggested: Local clone and then create a new project of type "PHP Application with Existing Sources".